# asp.net how do i transfer listbox values generated from a query to anoter listbox without a NullReferenceException error?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listbox

What i'm trying to do is to generate data on a ListBox from a query and then i can select some values, press a button and move those values to another ListBox.

When i try to move the values from a ListBox by the selecting the values and pressing the button i get the following error message:
System.NullReferenceException: `'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` i think this is because im making a reference to the value and i'm not creating an instance of the value (correct me if i am wrong)

To fix this i believe i might have to instantiate each query value in an array to add to the listbox.

If this is correct what is the correct way to implement that array?

**How i populate the ListBox**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    FillSitesListbox()
End Sub

Private Sub FillSitesListbox()

    Try
        dt = SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT s.Str_ID, s.Nm, d.str_grp_id, (Cast(s.Str_ID As varchar) + ' - ' + s.Nm + ' [ ' + Cast(d.str_grp_id As varchar) + ' ]' ) as IDDesc
                            FROM Retail_Store s left outer join store_group d on ( s.str_id = d.str_id ) 
                                ORDER BY s.Str_ID")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    SitesListBox.DataTextField = "IDDesc"
    SitesListBox.DataSource = dt
    SitesListBox.DataBind()
End Sub
```

**How i move values between ListBoxes**

```
Protected Sub FromSiteButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FromSiteButton.Click

    SitesListBox.Items.Add(StoresListBox.SelectedItem)
    SitesListBox.Items.Remove(SitesListBox.SelectedItem)

End Sub

Protected Sub FromStoreButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FromSTOREButton.Click

    StoresListBox.Items.Add(SitesListBox.SelectedItem)
    StoresListBox.Items.Remove(SitesListBox.SelectedItem)

End Sub
```

**How i execute a query**

```
Public Function ExecQuery(query As String) As DataTable

    Dim DBDT = New DataTable
    Using DBCon As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            DBCmd As New SqlCommand(query, DBCon)
        Params.ForEach(Sub(p) DBCmd.Parameters.Add(p))
        Params.Clear()
        DBCon.Open()
        DBDT.Load(DBCmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return DBDT
End Function

'Add Params
Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)
    Dim NewParam As New SqlParameter(Name, Value)
    Params.Add(NewParam)
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the code that moves the items is wrong.
In the first click (FromSiteButton_Click) you add the SelectedItem of the StoresListBox to the SiteListBox and then remove the SelectedItem from SitesListBox. I think you should add to the StoreListBox and remove from Sites selected item of that box. The same happens in the move FromStore

In any case, to avoid NRE you should always test if the reference variables that you are using are Nothing or not before using them

```
Protected Sub FromSiteButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FromSiteButton.Click

    If SitesListBox.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
        StoresListBox.Items.Add(SitesListBox.SelectedItem)
        SitesListBox.Items.Remove(SitesListBox.SelectedItem)
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub FromStoreButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FromSTOREButton.Click

    If StoresListBox.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
        SitesListBox.Items.Add(StoresListBox.SelectedItem)
        StoresListBox.Items.Remove(StoresListBox.SelectedItem)
    End If
End Sub
```